# Windows8 screen goes blank after screen saver is activated?

Tags: windows-8, crash, screensaver

I have a dell inspiron 13 7349 laptop running windows 8.  I have updated to the latest video driver.  When I try to preview a screen saver, the screen will go blank/black with only the mouse pointer visible.  The only way to get out of the blank screen is to restart the computer.  Does anyone have any ideas what is going on?

Here is the video driver information:

[image]

Comment: Try [Intel Driver Update Utility](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html) to update your PC drivers.

Comment: I tried using the intel driver update utility, but it says my video driver is already up to date.

Comment: May be the screen saver is corrupted. Is this happens for all screensaver (.scr) file?

Comment: I tried 3-4 different screen savers, same result.  Any other ideas?